# Bing maps on android app, any questions

Tags: android, bing, bing-api, bing-maps

Hi guys I'm new on android dev and I wanna ask you some questions about the potential of **bing maps** on android because `Google Maps` I've in my first app doesn't allow me on v2 api to remove business POI. So I've decided to use **bing maps** because I've seen that it has this opportunity, but I wanna ask you if I can call gmaps for navigation to a location from my app that use bing maps.

If you wanna suggest any other maps that allow to remove POIs made by map it's very appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, Bing Maps doesn't have an option to remove the POI's that are on the map tiles. Want to make sure you are aware of that before you get too far here. As for mixing the data from two different map providers, this isn't generally allowed. However if you are just launching the other app this shouldn't be much of an issue.

Comment: I've seen that I could remove POI with bing, but ok, I'll continue to use google maps also for a continuity on the system. Thank you so much for the explaination.

Comment: The Windows Store SDK for Bing Maps does allow to hiding/showing landmarks, but the map tiles themselves on all Bing Maps controls have POI locations such as bus stops written right on the tiles.